# MS Bot Framework VideoCard

Tags: botframework

Can someone please explain how you use the MediaUrl for the VideoCard?
I've tried just adding the video url to the CardMedia which loads the media player but I can't play the video.

And whatever I try with MediaUrl I just get an error saying MediaUrl is not a funtion.

```
var url = new MediaUrl("Test", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0i4v0Texqco");
var vid = new builder.Message(session)
          .textFormat(builder.TextFormat.xml)
          .attachments([
              new builder.MediaCard(session)
                  .title("Test title")
                  .media([
                      builder.CardMedia.create(session, url)
                  ])
          ]);
session.send(vid);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What channel are u using? Have you tried with a real video url and not with a YouTube video page?

Comment: Nope, haven't tried with a local video. Kinda need it to work by streaming it from some other source

Comment: I don't think having a YouTube URL is supported

Comment: Crap ^^
Have to think of somethig else then

Comment: What channel are u using?

Comment: If Ezequiel's answer helped, please select it as the selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the Javascript solution the following code works pretty well, please note that it has been tested in bot framework emulator.

```
const {ActivityTypes } = require('botbuilder');
async playYoutube(context)
{
    const reply = { type: ActivityTypes.Message };
    reply.attachments = [this.getInlineAttachment()];
    await context.sendActivity(reply);
}
```

get the object:

```
getInlineAttachment() {
    return {
        name: 'YoutubeVideo',
        contentType: 'video/mp4',
        contentUrl: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2JRiv3Mycs'
 }
```

hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Per the [VideoCard documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/core-concepts/reference/#videocard) and the [MediaUrl documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/core-concepts/reference/#mediaurl) the url must be the one to the source of the video.

Using a YouTube URL in the VideoCard is not supported.

However, recently a "YouTube Card" was recently added to the WebChat/Emulator. If you are using WebChat, you might consider using that. See [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1984) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/303) for more information.