# Failed to fetch the file from the url

Tags: botframework

This is an error thrown in botframework dashboard (issues).

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Failed to fetch the file from the url","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":2018008,"fbtrace_id":"CyiaDTS8Rjz"}}
```

This happens when i try to post videoCard.

My code :

```
  resultMessage.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
  resultMessage.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
  VideoCard video = new VideoCard()
  {
   Title = "title",
   Media = getMedia(activities[counter]),
  };
 resultMessage.Attachments.Add(video.ToAttachment());
```

and getMedia function :

```
public IList<MediaUrl> getMedia (ActivityModel model)
        {
            IList<MediaUrl> mediaUrl = new List<MediaUrl>();
            MediaUrl item = new MediaUrl();
            item.Url = model.DocumentPath;
            mediaUrl.Add(item);
            return mediaUrl;
        }
```

model.Document path is simple youtube video ...

Any idea ?

Comment: What channel are u using? You can't use a YouTube video URL as a the source of a video...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534155/ms-bot-framework-videocard/42559676#42559676

Comment: Sorry. I forget to mention that ... i'm using Facebook channel. It works for web chat channel : http://prntscr.com/eh1dra

But this error has been thrown by Facebook.

Comment: Yes, WebChannel has support for YouTube video per the post I added in my previous comment.

Comment: So how to use videocard to post youtube video ? I tried with hero and thumbnail but it does not work.

Comment: How to post youtube video correctly ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534155/ms-bot-framework-videocard/42559676#42559676
Here is mentioned that youtube card is added. I'm using latest botframework (C#) but there is no youtube card. 3.5.3 version

Comment: It said it was added for WebChat and Emulator. No you tube card in c#

Comment: I tried also this: 

`resultMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
                        {
                            ContentUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch? v=WxhTbxMSvT0",
                            Name = "name", 
                            ContentType = "playVideo",
                        });`

But it does not work. So it is not implemented yet ?? Or ?

Comment: A you tube video won't work

Comment: I hope there will be a fix for this... for now i will post only link...

Comment: What about vimeo ?